# MLA style month abbreviation with PHP date format?

Tags: php, date-formatting

For those of who haven't take a lit class in a while, MLA is Modern Language Style and months are abbreviated like this

- January - Jan.
- February - Feb.
- March - Mar.
- April - Apr.
- May - May
- June - June
- July - July
- August - Aug.
- September - Sept.
- October - Oct.
- November - Nov.
- December - Dec.

With PHP, it's easy to get either abbreviated or not

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $unformatted_date_string);
// abbreviated
echo $date->format('M d, Y');
// not abbreviated
echo $date->format('m d, Y');
```

But looked through http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php and not seeing a way to get a mix of both.  Is there a better solution than string parsing?

Comment: You mean you're passing a sting to createFromFormat() that contains the month in __both__ formats?

Comment: No, sorry that was a bit confusing.  $unformatted_date_string is entered thru a datepicker, so something like 2014/11/12

Comment: What I'm currently doing is $month = $date->format('m') then running that thru a switch case and returning the month string I need.  It's ok, but would be great to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: I think capital `J` is the one that does it, but I can't find it in the docs...

Answer (score 0):

You could always just format months which are greater than 4 characters in length. It seems like that's all that you really want to do.

```
// load array with all months for example
for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    $dates[] = new DateTime('2016-' . $x . '-1');
}

// length is > 4
// if: echo abbreviated month
// else: echo unformatted month
foreach($dates as $date) {
    if (strlen($date->format('F')) > 4) {
        echo $date->format('M') . ".";
    } else {
        echo $date->format('F');
    }

    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Results: 
`Jan. Feb. Mar. Apr. May June July Aug. Sep. Oct. Nov. Dec.`

[code on php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/iubh-5wax)

Comment: It doesn't work for September, output should be Sept.